# Internal/Home network reliability testing

Tags: home-networking

What is a good way to test internal network connectivity reliability?

We are experiencing intermittent issues accessing the internet.  We experience breakup more than we ought to with video conferencing.  When I connect directly to the cable modem (wired or wifi), things work as well as can be expected.  When I connect into some other point in the network (other wifi connected to the lan) we seem to have more troubles.

I have several switches and several wifi access points sprinkled throughout the house.  All of which eventually feed into the cable modem for internet access.

I have tried doing speed tests between devices (one directly to the cable modem and one elsewhere) and I get the expected speeds.  But I don't feel that it is really measuring reliability, and certainly it is not a long term test.

Are there any good tools out there?  I am a developer so I am capable of writing my own networking programs but I just wouldn't know what a good test would be in this situation.

Anyone have any thoughts?

Also, this is my first post here.  So if I violated any norms, please advise.  ;)

Thank you,
Joe

Comment: I looked at this issue: https://superuser.com/questions/1535902/how-to-identify-bottlenecks-in-my-home-network, so I will have to try if I can switch some networking gear around, but that could get expensive if I don't know which is problematic.

Comment: The only way I can think of is to connect to each device, perform a test with another device directly connected to the modem, and see if the problem happens.  This of course assumes you can recreate the problem.

Comment: @Ramhound - Maybe I could just setup a Jitsi server connected to the modem and test with that.  Sounds like a good weekend project.  Still, it's not a long term test, but it could prove better than nothing.

Comment: Try updating the firmware in devices attached to the ISP modem.

Comment: Since this is exclusively a WiFi issue, two obvious things to check would be noise or signal interference. You've already tools such as inSSIDer (https://www.techspot.com/downloads/5936-inssider.html) and Nirsoft''s WiFiInfoView (https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/wifi_information_view.html), I presume.

Comment: @John - Thanks for the suggestion.  I'll investigate.

Comment: @DrMoishe Pippik - Maybe I had too many edits to my question before I posted, but the problem is not only WIFI.  I see it from my work laptop too.  Though, there may be more than one problem.  I will look into those tools.  Thanks.